# Handling a Txt file content as a String Variable

Tags: python, json

I have a json file, and I need to read all of that json file content as String data. How can I read all the data and set a variable as a String for all of that content? Json file has blanks, new lines, special characters etc if it's neccesarry.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73524741/edit) to provide more information to your question.

Comment: For your purposes the fact that the file has JSON content is irrelevant. If you just want the content as a string then open the file and call the file handle's *read()* function

Answer (score 2):

```
import json
from ast import literal_eval

with open('<path_to_json_data>/json_data.txt') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f) # dict object
    print(json_data, type(json_data)) 
    
json_data_as_str = str(json_data) # dict-->str object
print(json_data_as_str, type(json_data_as_str)) 

data = literal_eval(json_data_as_str) # str-->dict object again
print(data, type(data))
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Simple as this example

```
import json

with open("path/to/json/filename.json", "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data)

dataStr = json.dumps(data)
print(dataStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

```py
import json

with open(file_name, "r") as fp:
    as_string = str(json.loads(fp.read()))
```

Comment: *as_string* will be a dictionary